# Is there a work around to the json unmarshaling bug on golang v1.4.0 of the Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps

When using the latest golang version v1.4.0 of the Google Maps API certain place_ids cannot be unmarshalled and the API throws an error:

Example code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"

    "googlemaps.github.io/maps"
)

func main() {
    // Set apiKey to a valid API key
    apiKey := "AIz....1c"
    mapsClient, err := maps.NewClient(maps.WithAPIKey(apiKey))
    placeID := "ChIJZ8MeRRouTI8REZAMtusUH3I"
    placesRequest := maps.PlaceDetailsRequest{
        PlaceID: placeID,
    }

    resp, err := mapsClient.PlaceDetails(context.Background(), &placesRequest)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Printf("%v", resp)
    }
}
j
```

It throws the error `json: cannot unmarshal array into Go struct field PlaceDetailsResult.result.secondary_opening_hours of type maps.OpeningHours`

There is an issue logged for this google maps service, but there seems to be no urgency in getting it fixed. [#281](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go/issues/281)

Is there a known workaround?

This is an internal error in the API for a large number of place_ids, but not all of them.  Since it is an internal error in the API, I have not managed to find a way to circumvent it.

Comment: Have you already tried filing a bug in the [public issue tracker](https://developers.google.com/maps/support#issue_tracker)?

Comment: It looks like there is a fix for the bug, but it just has not been approved and put into a release yet. See (https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go/pull/283)[https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-go/pull/283]

Answer (score 0):

Google just released v1.5.0 which fixes this problem